# Vue Routerでネストされた型をPickしたい

Tags: vue.js, typescript

vue-routerのRoute型からmatchedのmetaのみを取り出したいです。
具体的には次のようにmatchedまでは取り出せましたが、metaのみを取り出す書き方がわからずエラーが出てしまっています。
解消方法を教えていただけると助かります。

```js
const to: Pick<Route, 'fullPath' | 'path' | 'matched'> = {
  fullPath: '/home',
  path: '/home',
  matched: [{ meta: { isPublic: true } }],
};
```

```
Type '{ meta: { isPublic: true; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'RouteRecord': path, regex, components, instances, propsts(2739)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type Meta = Route['matched'][number]['meta']
```

で取り出せます。
ただ、この type はそもそも export されているので、

```
import type { RouteMeta } from 'vue-router'
```

すれば十分説はあります。